# FileNotFoundException when attempting to open a file in a jar

Tags: java, file, jar, java-7, file-permissions

Say I have a jar call it `foo.jar` which contains a folder structure>

`---com
   |---company
       |---jar
           |---metadata
               |---service
                   |---config
                       |---foo.xml`

I then try to read the file from my code with

```
  FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/jar/foo.jar!/com/company/jar/metadata/service/config/foo.xml")
```

This fails with `java.io.FileNotFoundException foo.xml(Permission denied)`

The jar in question has: `-rw-r--r--` (644 if you prefer numeric)

What is causing this permissions problem? How can I fix it so as to avoid this happening in the future. And how do I configure mavan/intelliJ to install maven dependencies in such a way that this problem does not occur.

Comment: A .jar entry is not a separate file, it’s a sequence of bytes in an archive.  You cannot use FileInputStream to read a .jar entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the JAR, I think you should use [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) (for reading) instead of FileOutputStream (for writing).

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/path/to/jar/foo.jar!/com/company/jar/metadata/service/config/foo.xml")
```